# App Not Killing Completely

Tags: ios, swift, launch-screen

I am working on an app where i have to show the launch screen for little long so for that i have added a viewcontroller(1) in the main storyboard and deleted the view Controller in launchscreen.storyboard. Now the  viewcontroller(1) is acting as a launch screen that is being displayed for 3 seconds.
The issue is now when i am killing the app , and re opening it whatever was the last view controller blinks for a few seconds and then the  viewcontroller(1) comes then the flow begins.
I thought it is a fault in my device and i checked in the similator but the simulator shows the app on re launching like BlackColorView ->  viewcontroller(1) -> Regular Flow.
Can i have any suggestions?

Comment: The image that iOS is displaying is the snapshot of the app right before it was killed. This does not mean the app is not getting killed. You need a splash screen which is displayed while the app is getting loaded into memory. For the effect you want, choose a splash screen (static image/layout) which looks exactly like the first screen of your app.

Comment: @ZeMoon i have few labels that have cornerRadius and Shadows so i am not finding splash screen usefull.

Comment: Also **do not** delay the startup of your app, just display some kind of loading screen. Delaying the start up of you app can make iOS kill the app since you should return a fast as possible form the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`